# Skew-symmetry of Lie brackets $[X,Y]=ad(X)Y$ on the space $T_e G$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $T_e G$ be the tangent space of the Lie group $G$ at the identity $e$ and
$[X,Y]=ad(X)Y$ be the Lie brackets,   where $ad$ is the differential of the adjoint representation at the identity that is $ad=T_e(Ad)$, and $Ad$ the adjoint representation $Ad(x)=T_e(C_x)$ where $C_x $ is conjugation by $ x $ (that is $C_x(g)=xgx^{-1})$

In the proof these brackets fulfill the axioms to form a Lie algebra.  In the proof for the skew-symmetry $[X,Y]=-[Y,X], \forall X,Y \in T_eG$ which is equivalent to $[Z,Z]=0, \forall Z \in T_eG $,

I have the following in my notes.

> Take $Z\in T_e G$, the map $t \to \exp(tZ) $is the exponential map
> $$\exp(tZ)=\exp(sZ)\exp(tZ)\exp(-sZ) \tag{0}$$
>
> $$\exp(tZ)=\exp(tAd(\exp(sZ))Z) \tag{1}$$
>
> Differentiating with respect to $t$ and evaluating at $t=0$, yields
>
> $$Z= Ad(\exp(sZ))Z \tag{2}$$
> Differentiating with respect to $s$ and evaluating at $s=0$, yields
> $$0= ad(Z)T_0(\exp)Z \tag{4}$$
>
> (...)

I am stuck at understanding this part. I have no idea how to get $(1)$.
I would just differentiate $(0)$  and  evaluate at $t=0$ as stated. I get the following:

$$Z\exp(tZ)|_{t=0}=\exp(sZ)Z\exp(tZ)\exp(-sZ)|_{t=0} $$

$$Z=\exp(sZ)Z\exp(-sZ)=C_{\exp(sZ)}Z \tag{3}$$

So what's wrong with (3)? How do I get (1),(2) and (4)?

Edit: This is lemma 4.9 in
[https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/lie2019/lie2010.pdf](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Eban00101/lie2019/lie2010.pdf)

Comment: Hi, looking at the text that you have linked, you get (1) because of lemma 4.3. $x exp(X) x^{-1} = exp(Ad(x)X)$. Remember that $exp(X)$ is the value at $t=1$ of $exp(tX)$ the curve that by definition has differential $X$ at $e$ when $t=0$. If we take the adjoint representation of $x$ and we want it to act on $X$, i.e. $Ad(x)X$ we will get another tangent vector in $T_e$. What is this vector? It will have to be the differential of the coniugation on my curve, $xexp(tX)x^{-1}$ but this is equivalent to the differential of a curve which is directly $exp(tAd(x)X)$. The two curves have same value

Comment: at $t=0$ so they must coincide I think. Then you just take $t=1$ and you get lemma 4.3. Your method seems a bit harder as the differentiation gets a bit more complex in that case, but I haven't tried to complete it. Hope this helps!

Comment: @l4teLearner  Thank you now (1) is clear. To go from (1) to (2). I think my method was incorrect, and that in the LHS $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\exp(tZ)=Z$ just because of the definition of integral curve. Now I still need to  justify the RHS

Comment: well think of $exp(sZ)$ as an element of the group. and $Ad(exp(sZ))$ is just its adjoint representation, that acts on elements of $T_e$. So in (1) the RHS just specified a curve with desired velocity $Ad(exp(sZ)Z$ makes sense? what is a bit involving here is that the argument of $Ad$ is an element of the group, but $Ad(something)$ as output of this process is again just a function on elements of $T_e$.

Comment: @l4teLearner Why does this curve $t\mapsto tAd(exp(sZ))$ has velocity Ad(exp(sZ)). I think I cannot differentiate as if it were a calculus 1 function

Comment: $s$ is fixed here, $t$ moves. the curve is not the one you wrote but is the RHS. I am not differentiating, just applied the definition of $exp$ as in 3.3 in your text.

Comment: @l4teLearner oh I see. Can you take a look at equation (4) that I just added. I am scratching my head here. I don't know how that $T_0(exp) $ shows up

Comment: and I don't know if I can just differentiate the LHS of (2) as if it were a calculus 1 constant function to get 0

Comment: I am not sure about that notation. but I would just skip that passage and look at the second equation of definition 4.5

Comment: @l4teLearner ok so (2) becomes. $\frac{dZ}{ds}|_{s=0}=\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}Ad(exp(sZ))Z$.  Now the LHS shuch be 0, but I am not sure why, is not like I can use the defition of integral curve here. And  what is also strange is that in the RHS that $Z$ seems to be just there unaffected by the 2 previous derivations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140223/discussion-between-l4telearner-and-mathlover).