# Can I multiply an element of a lie group with a vector of the tangent space at some point of the Lie group?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

My lecturer said I CANNOT multiply an element of a Lie group with a vector of the tangent space at some point of the Lie group. Why is that, it seems to me that he does it all the time, for instance
If $G$ is a Lie group, $e$ the identity element of the Lie group,
$Z \in T_eG$ to differentiate $\exp(tZ)$ at $t=0$ usually in my notes they just write without details that the result is $Z$. I think the details are these:

$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\exp(tZ)=Z\exp(tZ)|_{t=0} = Z \tag{1}$

In the last equality I have a multiplication of an element of the Lie group $\exp(tZ)$ with a tangent vector $Z$, so this contradicts what the lecturer said. So either the lecturer is wrong or this apparently simple derivation is not what I think
**Is this correct? Why is the lecturer's statement true(or false)?**

Comment: Here’s a good exercise for you. In the case $G$ is a matrix group, say $GL(n)$, show that the derivative of $L_A$ (at any group element) is again multiplication by $A$. Note that you can in this case multiply elements of the Lie algebra by elements of the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are writing $\exp(tZ)$ you are thinking of the function $f:t\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\mapsto\exp(tZ)\in G$. By definition, this is function is the unique solution of the differential equation $u'(t)=Z_{u(t)}$ with initial condition $u(0)=e$ (I am viewing the elements of the Lie algebra as left invariant vector fields), so *by definition* $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\Bigl|_{t=0}f(t)=f'(0)=Z_e.$$ So the equality you want to prove is actually part of the definition of $\exp$.

Comment: why should I care about left-invariance? Does that affect the value of the derivative at t=0?

Comment: I see, this  post was actually the giustification of the LHS of equation (2) in this other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563586/skew-symmetry-of-lie-brackets-x-y-adxy-on-the-space-t-e-g. If you have time take a look at it. The question there is actually how to get the right-hand side of (1)

Comment: Can I conclude that  writting $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\exp(tZ)=Z\exp(tZ)|_{t=0} $ is incorrect ? and that $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\exp(tZ)= Z$ should be written directly, precisely by definition of integral curve?

Comment: My point is that differentiating exp(tZ) as if it were a calculus1 function is incorrectly, even if after that evaluating at t=0 as if it were still a calculus 1  function yields Z which the correct answer.

Comment: Aren't they the same? since Z does not depend on t? Why don't they make sense?.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is more elementary than you might expect.

The function $L_g : G \to G$ defined by the formula $L_g(h)=gh$ is a diffeomorphism (which follows from the definition of a Lie group). That function therefore has a derivative, namely a smooth map $DL_g : TG \to TG$ defined on the tangent bundle $TG$, which restricts to a linear isomorphism from the tangent space $T_h G$ to the tangent space $T_{gh} G$, for each $h \in G$.

So when one speaks informally about "multiplying an element $g \in G$ by a vector $v$ in the tangent space", although your lecturer is  correct, one can nonetheless interpret the statement as meaning "applying the function $DL_g : TG \to TG$ to $v \in TG$".

---

Let me add a few words about your own calculations. I don't see any formal validity to your first equation. It does sort of look like a naive extension of a Calculus 1 derivation $\frac{d}{dt} \bigm|_{t=0} e^{kt} = k e^{kt} \bigm|_{t=0} = k$. But if that's what you meant then I'm sure you'll understand that you can't expect a Calculus 1 formula to apply in this context, despite how "naturally" it seems to come out.

Imagine the chaos unleashed on the world if one naively and "naturally" wrote $\exp(W)\exp(Z) = \exp(W+Z)$, in contrast to the actual result for $\exp(W) \exp(Z)$ given by the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).

Comment: what is wrong with my derivation in (1)? It must be wrong because I am getting that Zexp(tZ) that is supposed not to make sense, but it comes out naturally

Comment: It's because you're "hiding" the derivatives that Lee Mosher is mentioning.

Comment: @Randall Is there some theorem that states which are this derivates and lead to the right solution without incorrect steps?  The only derivative I see in (1) is d/dt

Comment: Could you please write what are the correct steps here  $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\exp(tZ)=.....= Z $ without hiding anything ?

Comment: yeah I understand that shouldn't expect a naive extension of calculus 1, but I am doing it like that because I having trouble finding what is the formal correct way to do that derivative. That's why I am asking what theorems I am not aware of are involved here

Comment: It seems, then, that the question you intended to ask is somewhat different than the question that you actually asked? Namely you want to know how to prove that equation $\frac{d}{dt}_{t=0} \exp(tZ)=Z$?

Comment: I guess. I didn't know there was so much behind that. I thought the answer of my question would take me inmediately to the answer of the second one

Comment: What’s the definition of $\exp$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't have an explicit formula I guess, it all  comes from a bunch of other definitions: $\exp$ is the exponential map. $ \exp: T_e(G)\mapsto G :X \to \alpha_x(1)$,  $\alpha_X $the maximal integral curve for $X\in T_e(G)$, the map $t \mapsto exp(tX)$  is a one parameter subgroup. I am following this notes https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/lie2019/lie2010.pdf but everything is so cryptic

Comment: The point is that the tangent vector of the curve $\alpha_X$ at $t=0$ is, by its very definition, the vector $X$. You are finding integral curves, indeed, of the left-invariant vector field whose value at $g$ is $(L_g)_*X$.